# Are these things rude?

Tags: politeness

Ok, I know I already asked this stuff but I thought that I should've organized it. So here it goes. By the way, quick shout out to people who answered my original question. I guess it was off-topic but I just wanted answers for something I've been wondering for a while. Also this is my first day on stack exchange. Sorry this is long:
1. Is saying "come on" and "let me" rude. And I mean let me in a way like "let me see that" and "let me have your phone". 
2. If it is rude to say commands without please,then why do people do it so often. (And I mean certain commands. Like, ones where please could be added appropriately)
3. Am I the only person who does say let me and come on? Also I don't use imperatives that much. I usually rephrase them to be statements and questions. Is that weird?

Comment: "Let me see that" *is* an imperative statement.  But an enormous amount of how such things are perceived has to do with the tone of voice.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't trying to be annoying I just thought I should have organized my question better. @Hot Licks

Comment: Hi, Pinkcat, you seem to have two user accounts. Please visit [the link](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and try to merge the two accounts if you want.

Comment: You should be aware that "come on" has two distinct meanings:  One is for cheering someone to victory or achieving a goal:  "Come on, keep going, you can do it."  The other is an expression of frustration.  When you're trying to watch TV and a family member stands between you and the TV and starts searching for something on the coffee table, you say, "Come on.  I'm trying to watch something here."  The first is never rude, but the second might be.

Comment: Whether it’s rude or just informal depends on the relationship between the speaker and the recipient.